# Remove the last value from the first key

Tags: python

I want to remove the last value from the first key for a dictionary, here is what I have:

```
{'attr1': ['Creativity','Control (1)','Passing (7)','Work Rate','Work Rate','Flair','Concentration'],
'attr2':['Creativity','Control (1)','Passing (7)','Work Rate','Work Rate','Flair']}
```

What I have tried:

```
for k,v in next(iter(player_data.items())):
    v.pop()
```

returns the error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I think because it stops being a dictionary?

So I have also tried:

```
for k,v in player_data.items():
    v.pop()
```

This however removes the last element for both keys.

Comment: `player_data['attr1'].pop()`?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Getting the key named `attr1` doesn't necessarily equate to getting the first key, as requested by the OP, unless `attr1` is always guaranteed to be the first key in the OP's input.

Comment: @blhsing "First" key in a dictionary doesn't really make sense as it's unordered.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Dicts have been ordered in Python for a while now, since version 3.6. OP's code also shows his/her intent by not naming the key, but instead iterating over the keys and getting the first one with `next`.

Comment: @blhsing Technically yes, but it's a bad practice to rely on it in most cases. So it depends on the OP's needs, but it seemed to me that by "first" (s)he meant the one that is first here so `'attr1'`. (S)He can use your answer or mine, depending on the needs.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I think the attempted code shows what the OP means by the first key rather clearly by not naming it but instead iterating through the keys as a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next(iter(player_data.items()))` already returns the first key-value pair, so you should not iterate over it with a `for` loop in your first attempt. Your second attempt would work if you simply break out of the loop unconditionally after popping the list.

However, since you only need to deal with the first value, you can get it directly with the `values()` method and pop it right away:

```
next(iter(player_data.values())).pop()
```